# 19.10 Xubuntu: Limiting battery charging - Lenovo Legion Y540

Tags: xubuntu, lenovo, battery, tlp

Using Xubuntu 19.10 on my Lenovo Legion Y540.
I would like to limit my battery to 80% while charging. Is it possible? 
I've tried using [TLP (with acpi_call etc...),](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tpacpi-bat) doesnt seems to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check first in the Bios of your laptop. Sometimes, the Bios provides options.

Comment: excuse me, is that possible to keep the battery in the laptop and using electricity and make battery using off ?